# How to drop a Redshfit database with connected users

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is it possible to drop active connections to Redshift in order to drop a database?

In my development environment I find myself recreating the schema very frequently and if there happens to be some stray process connected to the database this fails. I know it's possible to do this with Postgresql using `pg_terminate_backend`, but this doesn't seem to work on Redshift.

Deleting rows from the `STV_SESSIONS` table isn't an option, either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND.html

Find the PIDs of current running queries

```
 select pid from stv_recents where status = 'Running';
```

and terminate all the queries with

```
 select pg_terminate_backend(pid);
```

Comment: worth mentioning that you may have to look for the pid in another table though, like `select * from stv_sessions where db_name = 'mydb'` and get the pid from there